# FileNet P8 ACCE Sweep job filter

Tags: filenet-p8

I'm trying to setup a sweep job that moves a document from one class to a different class, but I only want to test right now -- not move ALL documents.

I was trying to add a filter to only pull over certain documents to test this before I pull the trigger, but it isn't working (ALL documents get listed in the results when I run this as preview).

The current filter I have is:

```
[DocumentTitle] like '%Z*%'
```

Any ideas what I need to do to change the filter to only have this run on the subset of documents I want??

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify on below queries to resolve your issue:

1) Is your sweep job based on Java API / .net API? or
2) Is it based on FEM (Enterprise manager) tool

From the Filter : [DocumentTitle] like "%Z%" will filter all documents with the title %Z%, Please try to filter with ID to fetch one record, Once successful, then test with multiple records.

Thanks,
Habi

Answer (score 0):

The sweep jobs typically take a condition that is similar to part after `WHERE` condition in search, the easiest way hence is simply to go to the search view, create your search, move to the SQL view tab, and then take whatever after `WHERE` condition and then add it to your sweep search filter.

Here are examples of filter conditions:

```
VersionStatus = 4 //All superseded documents
DateCreated < NOW() - TimeSpan(365, 'Days') //All documents that were created at least a year ago
StorageArea = OBJECT('{5E2BE09A-F4B1-49E2-A229-77FE32E5FEF1}') //All content in a specific storage area     
VersionStatus = 4 AND DateCreated < NOW() - TimeSpan(365, 'Days') AND ContentSize > (1024 * 1024 * 500) //Complex logical expression
```

Final point in regard to your question about

> I only want to test right now -- not move ALL documents.

Sweeps has `Sweep Mode` which defines how the sweep is going to execute, in your case you need to set it to `Preview`.